# Terraform 'aws_secretsmanager_secret' pass arn error: Invalid template interpolation value

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, secret-manager

I have a Lambda which will read a secret from Secret Manager, they all managed by Terraform.
So in Terraform I have a definition for this secret:

```
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "example" {
  name = "example"
}
```

and for Lambda, I have attached a permission to get the secret:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "example_role_policy" {
  name   = "example-role-policy"
  role   = aws_iam_role.example_lambda_role.id
  policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
.....(other needed permissions)
    },
    {
      "Sid": "GetDatabaseSecret",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Action": [
        "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue"
      ],
      "Resource": "${local.secret_arn}"
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}
```

I have `secret_arn` defined in variables:

```
locals{

secret_arn = "arn:aws:secretsmanager:::us-east-1:${local.account_number}:secret:${aws_secretsmanager_secret.example}-*"

}
```

When I apply Terraform, it gave me error:

```
Error: Invalid template interpolation value

  on ..\..\xxx\terraform\variables.tf line 39, in locals:
  39:   secret_arn = "arn:aws:secretsmanager:::us-east-1:${local.account_number}:secret:${aws_secretsmanager_secret.example}-*"
    |----------------
    | aws_secretsmanager_secret.example is object with 12 attributes

Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.
```

I tried to replae `*`with `??????` in the `secrect_arn` but still not working, couldn't find anything useful online, might someone be able to help? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `local.secret_arn` should be using `${aws_secretsmanager_secret.example.name}-*"`, not `${aws_secretsmanager_secret.example}-*"`.

But the **easiest way** to get the arn in your policy it would be simply:

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "example_role_policy" {
  name   = "example-role-policy"
  role   = aws_iam_role.example_lambda_role.id
  policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
.....(other needed permissions)
    },
    {
      "Sid": "GetDatabaseSecret",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Action": [
        "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue"
      ],
      "Resource": "${aws_secretsmanager_secret.example.arn}"
    }
  ]
}
POLICY
}
```

Comment: Ha should've noticed it, sorry for the stupid question....

Comment: @Cecilia No problem. I don't think your mistake was "stupid". Your question will help others in future with similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but I think you're overthinking it.
Try this:

```
secret_arn = aws_secretsmanager_secret.example.arn
```

Remember you're setting the account ID and region when you setup the AWS provider with:

```
provider "aws" {
  alias   = "ireland" # Your is in america but you get what I mean :)
  version = "2.70.0"
  region  = "eu-west-1"
...
```

Comment: Hi you're completely right, it should be the `.arn`

Comment: If this helps. Always look at the syntax almost as a hierarchy. I read it in that order. So resource type first dot resource name dot the thing you want to reference. If that makes sense. Here you wanted to reference the arn, but if it was name it would've been dot name.